# How do I set Particle.js bubble to reveal background image on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, particles

I wanted to recreate the effect shown in this page:

https://revolution.themepunch.com/particle-effect-for-wordpress/

[But I can't get the bubble to be tranparent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUuHr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you can set bubble opacity from default to something like .5 ... you can change it from 0 to 1.0